# Time based on country and region

Tags: php

How could I get the time, based on a country and a region ISO codes (e.g. 'AU' and 'QLD', 'US' and 'AK')?

I found about getting timezone via the `geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region` function and setting it in the DateTime object, but it's not compatible with PHP 7.3

Comment: Could you please reformat your post so it contains a question?

Comment: Are "regions" guaranteed to only have one timezone…? There certainly are areas in the US where timezones vary even within a state. Not sure if those would be distinguished by different regions…